# Background color of child element changed by parent background?

Tags: html, css

Html:

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Css:

```
body{
    background:#f06226;//dark orange
}

#container{
    background:rgba(255,165,0, 0.8);//orange
}
```

When I change background color to black `rgb(0, 0, 0)`, the container background changes to brown instead of remaining orange. Why does this happen and how do I prevent it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have opacity defined on your `#container` background.

```
background:rgba(255,165,0, 0.8);//orange
```

The `0.8` defines an 80% opacity so your #container has some transparency, which causes the black background from your `body` to blend in. You can change that to a `1` OR change your `#container` code to `background:rgb(255,165,0);//orange`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the opacity of .8 is causing the two colors blend.  Try changing the last number in the `container` style from `0.8` to `1`.